Fluttertts package, Detected as Suspicous Package by Antivirus App
I am trying to build build and app where i have used Fluttertts package for text recognition. But when i install the app on device containing Antivirus app, the app is detected as Suspicious and giving warning.
Suspicious app detected!
Demo has been reported as a suspicious app.
I have used the latest package from pub.dev
flutter_tts: ^4.0.2
final FlutterTts flutterTts = FlutterTts();
I have called below method, in initState method
Future<void> _speak() async { await flutterTts.speak("Hello, Good morning"); }
I have called the below method in dispose method
 Future<void> pauseFluttertts() async { await flutterTts.pause(); }
